# Scala run program with JVM

Tags: scala, compilation, jvm

I'm trying to run a simple Scala code using JVM. I compiled this using `scalac src.scala` with no errors. When I run this with scala it works properly. 
The problem is when I try to run it using:

```
java -cp ~/scala-2.11.7/lib/scala-library.jar MyObj
```

It gives me this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class MyObj
```

What is the problem here?

Here is my Scala code:

```
object MyObj {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Hello, world!")
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the object should extend the `App` trait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typically use this command.

`$> java -cp $SCALA_HOME/lib/scala-library.jar;. MyObj`

Comment: Thanks. I'm using OS X, and here I should replace ; with : it works now.